# Consulta técnica sobre armado de sección en Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, css3

Estoy armando un maquetado de esta  [PAGINA WEB](http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/) y estoy teniendo problemas en la sección de las cuatro imágenes (donde dice "viajá por Argentina") que se encuentra en la parte media del maquetado, el problema que me surge es cuando hago responsive el sitio. Me esta generando unos blancos en la adaptación y acomodamiento de las mismas y no se como arreglar eso para que se logren adaptar si es a través de mediaquerie o si eso directamente desde el CSS adjunte. 
Adjunto el código que adapte para esa parte.

```js
//funcion de los hover de las imagenes mayores
$(".hover").mouseleave(
  function () {
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

```css
figure.snip1281 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 288px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
figure.snip1281 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1281 img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip1281:after {
  background: #000000;
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
figure.snip1281 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
figure.snip1281 h2,
figure.snip1281 span {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip1281 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1281 span {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1281 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
figure.snip1281.blue:after {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
figure.snip1281.blue span {
  color: #409ad5;
}
figure.snip1281.red:after {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
figure.snip1281.red span {
  color: #d65548;
}
figure.snip1281.yellow:after {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}
figure.snip1281.yellow span {
  color: #f5b043;
}
figure.snip1281.green:after {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
figure.snip1281.green span {
  color: #36d278;
}
figure.snip1281:hover img,
figure.snip1281.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
figure.snip1281:hover:after,
figure.snip1281.hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}


figure.snip1282 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 547px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
figure.snip1282 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1282 img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip1282:after {
  background: #000000;
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
figure.snip1282 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
figure.snip1282 h2,
figure.snip1282 span {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip1282 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1282 span {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1282 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

figure.snip1282.green:after {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
figure.snip1282.green span {
  color: #36d278;
}
figure.snip1282:hover img,
figure.snip1282.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
figure.snip1282:hover:after,
figure.snip1282.hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <section>
      <div class="container-fluid sin-padding">
      <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 sin-padding">
            <div class="imagen-destacada">
              <figure class="snip1281 yellow">
                 <img class="img-responsive img-1" src="images/imagen-beneficios.jpg" >
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Gordon Norman</h2><span>Musician</span>
              </figcaption>
              <a href="#"></a>
              </figure>
             </div>            
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 sin-padding">
          <div class="imagen-destacada-medio">
            <figure class="snip1281 red hover">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="images/imagen-novedades.jpg">
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Abraham Pigeon</h2><span>Explorer</span>
              </figcaption>
              <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="snip1281 blue">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="images/imagen-soy-cliente.jpg">
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2><span>Artist</span>
              </figcaption>
              <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7 sin-padding">
          <div class="imagen-destacada-medio">
            <figure class="snip1282 green">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images/imagen-novedades-2.jpg">
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2><span>Artist</span>
              </figcaption>
              <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>          
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>  
    </section>
```

Comment: Primero que todo, dejame decirte que tiene un excelente diseño tu maquetacion WEB y segundo, solo debes especificarle que al estar en pantallas pequeñas, cada `div` que contiene a su respectiva imagen ocupe el 100% para que no queden esos espacios que mencionas.

Comment: Cambia los `col-xs-6` a `col-xs-12`, recuerda que tambien puedes usar `FlexBox` es sencillo y te permite trabajar para **Responsive Design**

Comment: @ChechoParrado gracias por tu comentario, pero vos decis en width y height que les ponga 100%?

Comment: y como se usa el flexbox que es lo que te permite hacer?

Comment: No, con lo de ponerle al 100% es con la etiqueta `col-xs-12` y si estas usando Boostrap recuerda que con 12, ocupas todo el espacio de una fila, osea el 100%, a eso me refiero y **FlexBox** es una serie de  herramientas que se trabaja desde `Css` para realizar paginas adaptables a múltiples pantallas.